# Subtracting from an Array, coding challenge

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to solve this coding challenge and want to know why my code isn't working. Please let me know what the problem is and suggest an alternative solution.

**Here is the question:**
Create a function called 'reversedLooper' that when passed an array will loop through it backwards and subtract 2 from the last element, 1 from the second to last, 0 from to the third to last, add one to the fourth to last, add 2 to the fifth to last, etc. until it reaches the front of the array.  Return the list when you are done

**Here is my solution**

```
var arr = [2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 19]; 
var difference = [];
var arr3 = [];

//the function below is working correctly in the way I intend...

function arrayCreator (arr3) { 
    var i;
    for(i = arr.length - 3; i >= -2; i--) {
        arr3.push(i);
    }
    return arr3;
}


function reversedLooper (arr) {
    var i;
    for(i=0; i< arr.length; i++) {
        var pusher = arr[i] - arr3[i];   
        difference.push(pusher);
    }

    return difference;
}

console.log(reversedLooper(arr));

// answer should be [5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 17] in this case
```

Comment: What's the output that you're getting?

Comment: you're not looping from it backwards in reversedLooper.  Also you are referencing arr3 which is empty.  And what is arrayCreator for??  Are you sure you tried the best you could?

Comment: wow why all the down votes? I'm new to this but didn't think this was a bad question

Comment: @ergonaut arr3 will not be empty after the first function (I forgot to invoke it) anyway I'm sorry if it was a bad question and I appreciate everyone's response

Comment: @LukeSchunk Did you read my answer?

Comment: @PraveenKumar i did, thanks - I'll have to look up the map( ) and reverse( ) functions to better understand your solution - I haven't yet learned those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an auxiliar variable starting at 2 and decrementing it each iteration, take a look:

```js
function reversedLooper(arr) {
  for (var i = arr.length - 1, numToSum = 2; i >= 0; i--, numToSum--) {
    arr[i] = arr[i] - numToSum;
  }
}

var arr = [2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 19];
reversedLooper(arr);
document.write(arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `map()` function and `reverse()` functions:

```
count = -3;
finalArray = [2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 19]
                .reverse()
                .map(function (obj) {
                   count++;
                   return obj + count;
                 })
                 .reverse();
```

Executing on console gives this:

```
» count = -3; [2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 19].reverse().map(function (obj) { count++; return obj + count; }).reverse()
« [5, 5, 4, 5, 6, 17]
```

**Snippet**

```js
count = -3;
final = [2, 3, 3, 5, 7, 19].reverse().map(function(obj) {
  count++;
  return obj + count;
}).reverse();
alert(final.join());
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code just declare the arrayCreator function without invocation.
And also `var pusher = arr[i] + arr3[i];`  Edited these two things and your code will work.

Comment: hey, you're right it works now, thanks a lot. noob mistake of mine not invoking the function..but thanks for taking the time to look at my code and see what I was doing wrong

Comment: @LukeSchunk my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

change the function reversedLooper to:

```
function reversedLooper(arr){
  var x=-2;
  for(var i=arr.length-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
    arr[i]+=x;
    x++;
  }
  return arr;
}
```